# Vanity URLs with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, vanity-url

I need to implement vanity urls and this is my `.htaccess` file

```
# check if mod_rewrite is present
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  #turns it on
  RewriteEngine on

  #if the requested url isn't a file or a dir
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  #if the request does not end with .gif, .png or .jpg
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.gif|\.jpg|\.png)$ [NC]

  #process book.php, no matter what was in the url
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /book.php?book_id=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

This translation works correctly.

```
www.mydomain.com/foo -> www.mydomain.com/book.php?book_id=foo
```

Now i need a more specific condition:

```
www.mydomain.com/foo/readers -> www.mydomain.com/book.php?book_id=foo&readers=1
```

While `readers` doesn't change, `foo` is a random string and i'd like to check this specific url

```
www.mydomain.com/foo/readers -> valid
www.mydomain.com/foo/readers?q=hello -> valid
www.mydomain.com/foo/reader -> invalid
www.mydomain.com/foo/readers/bar -> invalid
www.mydomain.com/foo/bar/readers -> invalid

#I tried many solutions like this but i can't get the desired result
RewriteRule ^(.*)[/]readers /book.php?book_id=$1&readers=1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use anchor in your rule and make trailing slash optional:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/readers/?$ /book.php?book_id=$1&readers=1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I have an issue when trying to change the hash on this url on a button click: `www.mydomain.com/foo/readers` -> `window.location.hash = '#something';` I can't understand why `www.mydomain.com/foo/readers/#something` or `www.mydomain.com/foo/readers#something` are redirected.

Comment: I am on mobile as I am traveling for next few days. What exact problem are you facing after that JS code executes? Does it trigger a request to web server or not?

Comment: Yes, it redirects to `www.mydomain.com/foo`. But it's strange, if i write `window.location.hash = '#something';` in `Chrome` console works good, if i use jquery to implement button click it works good (so i resolved but i didn't understand). Issue is when i use `href="javascript:myMethod();"` it doesn't work. (`myMethod(window.location.hash = '#something';)`)

Comment: I believe that is because part after # is handled in JS itself and is not passed over to Apache.